Anchor test as job in github CI
What is the most effective way to set up anchor test running in a Github job for the CI pipeline?
There are some old tutorials for this involving Serum's docker images, but in 2024, what is the best approach?
Here's an example test.yaml:
  env:
     RUST_TOOLCHAIN: 1.75.0
     SOLANA_CLI_VERSION: 1.18.11
     ANCHOR_CLI_VERSION: 0.30.1

  jobs:
  # Other jobs...

  localnet-test:
    name: Anchor localnet tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # boilerplate to set up node, rust, solana, anchor...

      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Build program
        run: anchor build -p someprogram -- --no-default-features

      - name: Run tests
        run: anchor test --skip-build

Even with a fairly long test startup, it fails with Unable to get latest blockhash. Test validator does not look started.
Locally, the test starts in 1-2 seconds and finishes in 8.6s.

Most likely, the test validator in the CI environment isn't booting up fast enough and running into this error: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/7cb20f255687cd0df887b0289f12a9fa50a5aa08/cli/src/lib.rs#L3670-L3677
By default, it waits 5 seconds, so maybe that number needs to be bumped out: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/7cb20f255687cd0df887b0289f12a9fa50a5aa08/cli/src/config.rs#L763
Configuration is a bit tricky, but it looks like you can tweak TestValidator to do that by setting:
[test]
startup_wait = 10000

According to https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/anchor-toml_reference.html?highlight=test%20validator#startup_wait

This is the right answer, but in some cases I've had it that the validator errors out for some other reason, and in that case editing the startup_wait time won't work. Make sure to check inside .anchor/validator.log as well for any error messages.

@JonCFan how do you check the logs inside a CI environment? The test starts/runs locally so local logs aren't an option.

This should do the trick: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs-and-deployments/managing-workflow-runs/downloading-workflow-artifacts
